# Search 2D ArrayList by user input & display row in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having a little trouble with a fairly simple assignment, but couldn't find an answer here that seemed to work.

I need to have a 2D ArrayList that contains staff data, and then be able to run a separate function that allows the user to input a staff member's name, searches the ArrayList for that name, and if it exists, display the full row of data.

Here's what I've got so far:

The ArrayList

```
List<List<String>> staffArrayString = new ArrayList<>();
staffArrayString.add(Arrays.asList("Steven George", "12 York Road", "07123456678", "Permanent", "York", "27000/yr"));
staffArrayString.add(Arrays.asList("Rina Veyer", "20 Leeds Road", "08987987765", "Part Time", "Leeds", "10/hr"));
staffArrayString.add(Arrays.asList("Brian Lym", "13 Bradford Road", "07123234345", "Permanent", "Bradford", "27000/yr"));
```

The search function

```
public void staffNameSearch() {
    System.out.println("Enter name of staff member:");
    String staffName = in.next();
    boolean found = false;
    int row = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < staffArrayString.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < staffArrayString.get(i).size(); j++) {
            if (staffArrayString.get(i).get(j).equals(staffName)) {
                row = staffArrayString.get(i).size();
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (found = true) {
        System.out.print(staffArrayString.get(row) + " ");
    }
}
```

I'm currently getting an output of 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException' at the print line on the end there, but I can't for the life of me work out why. I'd appreciate any advice on this (especially if it's some obvious and stupid mistake on my part!).

Comment: What line throws the Exception?

Comment: @Stewart sorry, forgot to specify that. It's the print line at the end of the search function, edited to add it.

Comment: Debug by putting `System.out.print("row == " + row + "; staffArrayString.length() == " + staffArrayString.length()` just before that line.

Comment: Is the `< =` a typo here: `for (int i = 0; i < =staffArrayString.size(); i++) {`

Comment: @ASutherland yep, it was... I swear I'll learn to type one day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The error is occuring because you are setting row to something unrelated to the row counter.  When you discover the row (variable `i`) which has the name in the `j`th element, set `row=i`.
2. Be careful about `if (found = true)` - it is incorrect; prefer:

   - a) `if (found)`
   - b) `if (found == true)`
3. For efficiency, include `&& !found` in the for loops so they exit as soon as you find something.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! Also additional thanks for picking up on the missing equals sign, I'm still slipping up on that occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for each loop for simpler.

```
System.out.println("Enter name of staff member:");
String staffName = in.next();
boolean found = false;
String[] foundArray;
for(String[] staffArray: staffArrayString){
     for(String str : staffArray){
          if(str.equals(staffName)){
           foundArray = staffArray;
           found = true;
           break;
          }
     }  
}
if (found == true) {
    System.out.print(foundArray + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to simplify the code a little bit by using a Map and a Staff class.

For example, the Staff class

```
public class Staff{
    String name;
    String address;
    String id; // ?
    boolean permanent; // Or a enum if there are more than 2 values
    String city; // ?

    int payrate;
    boolean hourly;

    @Override
    public String toString(){ // Easily convert the class to a String
        return String.format("%s %s %s %s %s $%d/%s", 
                    name,
                    address,
                    id,
                    permanent ? "Permanent" : "Part-time",
                    city,
                    payrate,
                    hourly ? "hr" : "yr");
    }
}
```

And for the code to read it

```
private Map<String, Staff> staffDirectory; // String is the name in lowercase

public void staffNameSearch() {
    // Code
    if(staffDirectory.containsKey(staffName)){ // Make sure staffName is lowercase
          System.out.print(staffDirectory.get(staffName) + " ");
    } else {
          System.out.println("Name not found");
    }
}
```

This way you can avoid using loops and get O(1) efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll definitely look into using something like this in future, it does look a lot simpler and more efficient!